# Optimizing O(m n) solution for longest common subsequence challenge

Tags: c++, optimization, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming, time-limit-exceeded

> Given two strings string `X` of length `x1` and string `Y` of length `y1`, find the longest sequence of characters that appear left to right (but not necessarily in contiguous block) in both strings.
>
> e.g. if `X = ABCBDAB` and `Y = BDCABA`, the `LCS(X,Y) = {"BCBA","BDAB","BCAB"}` and `LCSlength` is 4.

I used the standard solution for this problem, whichever is greater:

- `if(X[i]=Y[j]) :1+LCS(i+1,j+1)`
- `if(X[i]!=Y[j]) :LCS(i,j+1)`
- `LCS(i+1,j)`

and then I used memorization, making it a standard DP problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int LCS[1024][1024];
int LCSlen(string &x,int x1,string &y,int y1){
    for(int i = 0; i <= x1; i++)
    LCS[i][y1]=0;

    for(int j=0;j<=y1;j++)
    LCS[x1][j]=0;

    for(int i = x1 - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    for(int j = y1 - 1; j >= 0; j--){

    LCS[i][j] = LCS[i+1][j+1];

    if(x[i] == y[j])
    LCS[i][j]++;

    if(LCS[i][j+1]>LCS[i][j])
    LCS[i][j]=LCS[i][j+1];

    if(LCS[i+1][j]>LCS[i][j])
    LCS[i][j]=LCS[i+1][j];

    }
    }
return LCS[0][0];
} 

int main()
{
string x;
string y;
cin >> x >> y;
int x1 = x.length() , y1 = y.length();
int ans = LCSlen( x, x1, y, y1);
cout << ans << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Running [here](http://ideone.com/hfLwnh), this solution I used in [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/LCS0/) and I got a time limit exceeded and/or runtime error.

Only 14 solutions are yet accepted.  Is there a smarter trick to decrease the time complexity of this question?

Comment: I don't have the time to write a full out answer, but you should use `memset(LCS, 0, sizeof(LCS[0][0]) * x1 * y1);` instead of those 2 `for` loops at the beginning in order to zero out your matrix.

Comment: but that doesn't optimize it much .

Comment: SPOJ mentions that a string may have 50000 letters. Your code handles no more that 1024. That definitely accounts for a runtime error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is correct, but the implementation is sort of naive; it definitely doesn't scale to 50000-long strings. Even for the 1024-long strings it is very cache-unfriendly; most likely you spend most of the time in cache misses.

The [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Reduce_the_required_space) mentions that

> dynamic programming approach only needs the current and previous
>   columns of the matrix

Modify your code to run in a linear space. That shall give you a boost.

Answer (score 1):

Although I still didn't get an AC because of time limit exceeded ,I was however able to implement the linear space algorithm.In case anyone wants to see, here is the c++ implementation of the Hirschbirg algorithm.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int* compute_help_table(const string & A,const string & B);
string lcs(const string & A, const string & B);
string simple_solution(const string & A, const string & B);

int main(void) {
    string A,B;
    cin>>A>>B;

    cout << lcs(A, B).size() << endl;

    return 0;
}

string lcs(const string &A, const string &B) {
    int m = A.size();
    int n = B.size();

    if (m == 0 || n == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    else if(m == 1) {
        return simple_solution(A, B);
    }
    else if(n == 1) {
        return simple_solution(B, A);
    }
    else {
        int i = m / 2;

        string Asubstr = A.substr(i, m - i);
        //reverse(Asubstr.begin(), Asubstr.end());
        string Brev = B;
        reverse(Brev.begin(), Brev.end());

        int* L1 = compute_help_table(A.substr(0, i), B);
        int* L2 = compute_help_table(Asubstr, Brev);

        int k;
        int M = -1;
        for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            if(M < L1[j] + L2[n-j]) {
                M = L1[j] + L2[n-j];
                k = j;
            }
        }

        delete [] L1;
        delete [] L2;

        return lcs(A.substr(0, i), B.substr(0, k)) + lcs(A.substr(i, m - i), B.substr(k, n - k));
    }
}

int* compute_help_table(const string &A, const string &B) {
    int m = A.size();
    int n = B.size();

    int* first = new int[n+1];
    int* second = new int[n+1];

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        second[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            first[k] = second[k];  
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(j == 0) {
                if (A[i] == B[j])
                    second[1] = 1;
            }
            else {
                if(A[i] == B[j]) {
                    second[j+1] = first[j] + 1;
                }
                else {
                    second[j+1] = max(second[j], first[j+1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    delete [] first;
    return second;
}

string simple_solution(const string & A, const string & B) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < B.size(); i++) {
        if(B.at(i) == A.at(0))
            return A;
    }

    return "";
}
```